# ERROR by CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks

Поставил CodeBlocks 13.12. При запуске дебага выдаёт следующее:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings.
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes))
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))
```

Comment: I believe, you need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings.
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes))
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))

Answer (score 1):

- В Code::Blocks IDE, выберите **Settings** -> **Debugger**.
- В дереве справа выберите **Common** -> **GDB/CDB debugger** -> **Common**.
- В диалоге слева введите **Executable path** и выберите 
  **Debugger type** = GDB или CDB.

<sub>оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083560/how-do-you-specify-a-debugger-program-in-codeblocks-12-11</sub>

Comment: Что ввесли в строку Executable path?
Debugger type выбран GDB.
Снизу стоят 4 верхние галочки.

Comment: путь к gdb. просто `gdb.exe`, если он  вас в `%path%`.

Comment: В папке проги такого файла нет.

Comment: Нет. это внешний отладчик. Поставьте по ссылке из вики: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=MinGW_installation#gdb_debugger

Comment: Спасибо — помогло! А подскажите ещё, как оставить консоль открытой, после обработки кода (сейчас так быстро обрабатывает и закрывается, что не успеваю ничего просмотреть).

Comment: Не подскажу. у меня и code blocks нет, если честно. задавайте отдельным вопросом.